# Windows 10 not reporting RAID correctly

Tags: external-hard-drive, raid

I just installed 4 x Western Digital Red 6TB NAS HDD's into a Vantec HX4R enclosure and set the RAID to 5.  The JMicron HW Raid Manager Software that came with the enclosure shows all 4 Disks 5588.97GB. But under Windows 10 Disk management it shows up as one drive and only 16766.35 GB.Have I configured the RAID correctly?
The HX4R has 4 mechanical toggle switches that indicate RAID types.This is set to RAID5.

Comment: This all seems perfectly fine. Do you have some reason to think something is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It is working perfectly.  The NAS combined the 4 disks into a RAID5 volume and tells Windows there is only 1 drive and volume.  Since RAID5 uses the equivalent of one drive's storage space as parity for redundancy (by default) your four 5.5 GB drives show up as 16766.  This allows for one drive to fail, yet everything will still work with no data loss.

If you want ALL the space available for storage, you would need RAID0.  RAID0 would give you all the storage available, but you would have no redundancy.  If a drive was lost in this RAID configuration, all your data would be gone.